# Error in installing vcf2maf

Tags: vcf, maf

I tried to install `vcf2maf` following this tutorial from GitHub: https://github.com/mskcc/vcf2maf.

I get a repeat error when I try to test out vcf2maf using the code:

```
perl vcf2maf.pl --input-vcf tests/test.vcf --output-maf tests/test.vep.maf
```

The error message looks like this:

```
'''STATUS: Running VEP and writing to: tests/test.vep.vcf
ERROR: Cannot find VEP script under: /Users/user/miniconda3/bin'''
```

Basically I followed every steps provided on the tutorial.
Does anyone could help me find out what is going wrong?

I am working on macOS Monterey 12.2.1 with an Intel Core i5 processor.

Comment: Could you kindly provide details of your hardware and system?

Comment: I have the same problem.
I tried conda installation as indicated, however, the error is not solved.
Perl version is v5.36.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install it via anaconda/conda either,

```
conda install -c bioconda vcf2maf
conda install -c bioconda/label/cf201901 vcf2maf
```

I would be surprised if that installation fails. A possible issue is Perl version and system version.

Comment: Thanks! I think that works!

Comment: Cool, please remember to 'accept' and if possible upvote